# Mongod with bind_ip error "Address already in use"

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to follow the **MongoDB** docs [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) on how to setup a replica set. The command example they provide has a `bind_ip` parameter, which is not working. If I run the command without it **mongod** runs normally, but if I include the command **mongod** says the address is already in use.

This is the output of the error:

### Run:

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27017 --bind_ip localhost,127.0.0.1 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

### Outputs:

```
2018-03-01T16:30:56.133-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1237 port=27017 dbpath=/srv/mongodb/rs0-0 64-bit host=maumau-pcm
2018-03-01T16:30:56.133-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2018-03-01T16:30:56.133-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2018-03-01T16:30:56.133-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
2018-03-01T16:30:56.133-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-03-01T16:30:56.133-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-03-01T16:30:56.133-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-03-01T16:30:56.133-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
2018-03-01T16:30:56.134-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-03-01T16:30:56.134-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-03-01T16:30:56.134-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "localhost,127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, replication: { oplogSizeMB: 128, replSet: "rs0" }, storage: { dbPath: "/srv/mongodb/rs0-0", mmapv1: { smallFiles: true } } }
2018-03-01T16:30:56.134-0300 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /srv/mongodb/rs0-0 created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-03-01T16:30:56.134-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2018-03-01T16:30:56.134-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-03-01T16:30:56.134-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-03-01T16:30:56.134-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7436M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-03-01T16:30:56.813-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519932656:813042][1237:0x7f58c353c580], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 10/768
2018-03-01T16:30:56.918-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519932656:918711][1237:0x7f58c353c580], txn-recover: Recovering log 10 through 11
2018-03-01T16:30:56.999-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519932656:999047][1237:0x7f58c353c580], txn-recover: Recovering log 11 through 11
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected configuration for non-active storage engine mmapv1 when current storage engine is wiredTiger
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-03-01T16:30:57.105-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-03-01T16:30:57.116-0300 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/srv/mongodb/rs0-0/diagnostic.data'
2018-03-01T16:30:57.117-0300 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local voted for document at startup.
2018-03-01T16:30:57.117-0300 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset
2018-03-01T16:30:57.118-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: listen: Address already in use, terminating
2018-03-01T16:30:57.118-0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-03-01T16:30:57.118-0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-03-01T16:30:57.118-0300 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing all drop-pending collections...
2018-03-01T16:30:57.118-0300 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing checkpointTimestamp collection...
2018-03-01T16:30:57.118-0300 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutting down replication subsystems
2018-03-01T16:30:57.118-0300 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2018-03-01T16:30:57.118-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2018-03-01T16:30:57.413-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519932657:413669][1237:0x7f58c353c580], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 11/4864
2018-03-01T16:30:57.526-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519932657:526610][1237:0x7f58c353c580], txn-recover: Recovering log 11 through 12
2018-03-01T16:30:57.606-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519932657:605999][1237:0x7f58c353c580], txn-recover: Recovering log 12 through 12
2018-03-01T16:30:57.789-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-03-01T16:30:57.789-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-03-01T16:30:57.789-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: It's a debian 8 distro.

Answer (score 0):

As [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) pointed out, the `--bind_ip` command expects either `domain-name` or `IP_ADDRESS`.

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27017 --bind_ip localhost \
    --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```